# Как сериализовать объект с циклическими зависимостями в json

Tags: javascript, json, циклы, сериализация, зависимости

Есть объект

```
let man = {
    "name":"Pasha",
    "age":20,
};
man.friend = man;
```

Его необходимо сериализовать. `JSON.stringify(man)`  выдает ошибку `Converting circular structure to JSON`

```js
let man = {
 "name":"Pasha",
 "age":20,
};
man.friend = man;

JSON.stringify(man)
```

П.С.: В ответе набросал костыль для решения этой задачи. Может быть есть варианты по-получше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let man = {
 "name":"Pasha",
 "age":20,
};
man.friend = Object.assign({},man);

console.log(JSON.stringify(man));
```

Comment: Интересно. По сути, моей целью была сериализация более зацикленных объектов. Типа `response, request` на сервере `NodeJs`, а в вопросе объект приведен в качестве примера. Мой способ работает для объектов любой вложенности. Ваш вариант надо как-то туда интегрировать

Comment: @Дмытрык, нет смысла пытаться полностью сериализовать `request`, `response`, учитывая, что там могут быть значения, которые в принципе нельзя сериализовать. Лучше просто выбрать нужные поля

Comment: @Grundy, всяких разных объектов на сервере много. И все их поля я не знаю. Хотелось иметь возможность инспектировать их в консоли браузера)

Comment: @Дмытрык, Все их знать и не обязательно. Для этого есть справка, в которой все описано.

Comment: Так погодите. Ваш вариант не работает, т.к. изначально нет зацикленности. Вы ее просто удалили и все

Comment: @Дмытрык, правильнее будет - он ее не добавлял.

Comment: @Grandy, точно. Но, все равно, благодаря, этому варианту, у меня появилась идея как усовершенствовать свой код). Сейчас изменю. Результат превысил все мои ожидания) Получилась полная сериализация)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let man = {
"name":"Pasha",
"age":20,
};
man.friend = man;

let arr=[];

function removeCircular(obj){
//проходим циклом по всем ключам
  for (key in obj){
let testObj = obj[key]
//каждый ключ пробуем сериализовать
try{
  JSON.stringify(testObj)
//если не получается, добавляем этот ключ (а по сути объект) в массив
}catch(err){
  arr.push(testObj);
 //проверяем ключ, на идентичность (объекты для сравнения лежат в массиве)
  let d = checkInstanse(testObj);
// если идентичных объектов найдено не было - ищем идентичности внутри этого ключа(объекта)
  if(!d){ 
    removeCircular(testObj)
  } else{
   delete obj[key]
   obj[key] = Object.assign({}, obj)
    
  }
} 
  }
}

function checkInstanse(obj){
  let returnObj;
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
if (Object.is(arr[i], obj)){
  returnObj = obj;
}
  }
  return returnObj
}

removeCircular(man);
console.log(JSON.stringify(man));
```